# How can I use integer n in StdOut.printf (JAVA)

Tags: java, format, printf

How can I write this if i want to replace 10 by n (where int n=10) :

```
StdOut.printf("%10s","Hello");
```

I tried to write :

```
int n=10;
StdOut.printf("%ns","Hello");
```

But it's wrong.. what's the solution?

Comment: It may depend on what `StdOut.printf` is, since that's not a Java library class method.

Comment: @AlanKrueger [`StdOut`](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdOut.java.html) looks as a wrapper class for `System.out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:-

```
 int n=10;
 StdOut.printf("%" + n + "s","Hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this: -

```
System.out.printf("%" + n + "s","Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
    int n=10;
    System.out.println("$n$s".replaceAll("$n$", n+""));
```

This will simply replace all values.